# How do i edit fields of default joomla registration/login/profile etc... forms? Joomla 3.8

Tags: default, joomla3.0, user-registration

Hi I am new in Joomla and i am trying to change the way my default forms look. For example, in the login form i would like to replace the default username field with an e-mail field, or in the user profile I would like to delete the confirm-email address field and add an image field (so every user can have his/her picture there).

How can i do this? I have searched online and can't find an answer. I have tried overwriting default files, searching for tutorials and still can't find the answer.

Help is greatly appreciated.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla you use overrides to change the default output of components and modules.

In summary, from the backend you go to Extensions > Templates > Styles. Then in the column title 'Template' click the name of your template, Protostar in the screenshot below.

[image]

Then select the 'Create Overrides' tab and locate the extension you want to override, in your case mod_login.

The original files for the extension will be copied to /templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/extension_name

You edit these files in your template directory and they will override the output of the component or module in question.

Check the section titled 'Creating Overrides' on https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager for full details on how this works.

Good luck!